# ssh forwarding error

Tags: ssh, juju, maas

I have some issues regarding SSH and i am unable to solve . I have completed bootstrap and node status is 1 node allocated to maas, Now when i do juju status, it says invalid ssh key , hostname cannot be found error. .. I then went to /etc/hosts file and i changed

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
```

to my

```
127.0.01     Node1
```

Now it gives me , error SSH forwading error: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

I also have run the node after bootstrap and it gives ssh key .. I didnt added any ssh key in my Dashboard of MAAS.

Secondly i want to ask how can i make more nodes allocated to root?

Do i have to rewrite the maas-oauth portion in environment with another API key . Kindly Reply ASAP ....

Answer (score 3):

You should leave the "localhost" text on the 127.0.0.1 line - various things depend on that existing.  Instead, you probably wanted to *add* your hostname to that line:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost node1
```

Your question also says "127.0.01" without the third "." - hopefully that's a typo in the question and not in your /etc/hosts file.

NOTE: [hostnames should always be lowercase](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123), case is ignored but that doesn't mean it won't cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Before juju will connect to the nodes, you must reboot them AFTER doing the juju bootstrap. This will cause them to install new software, including the keys necessary to enable communications.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is key has been alternate from the one exists in the `.ssh/known_hosts` file.

If you are certain the system has not been compromised, you can simply remove the host key in the `known_hosts` file and accept the new one again.